# Can't run an MPI program through mpirun command of OpenMPI implementation

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I have an MPI program (a code in c for a school project) that I want to run on more nodes (this time 2 nodes) but it doesn't work and it is infinitely waiting without any text/error.
I am trying to run it on both machines with command `mpirun -np 2 --host 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2 ./mandelbrot_mpi_omp` (ip addresses are just as placeholder, they are different in real and correct) on both nodes while providing the ip addresses in same order on both machines so the first one is always master with rank 0.

This MPI program main function code snippet (just in case... I don't think that here is the origin of MPI not working on more nodes, but I might be wrong.):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int width = SCALE_X;
    int height = SCALE_Y;

    // MPI init & setup
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int world_size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    // calculate size of buffer according to server count
    int part_height = SCALE_Y/world_size;
    int buffer_size = (width+1)*(part_height+1)*3;

    // dynamically allocate arrays for image data according to server count
    send_buffer = calloc( buffer_size, sizeof(PIXEL));
    recv_buffer = calloc( buffer_size*world_size, sizeof(PIXEL));

    if(rank == 0) printf("MPI node count: %i\n", world_size);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // OpenMP setup
    int cpu_count = omp_get_num_procs();
    omp_set_num_threads(cpu_count);
    printf("OpenMP cpu count on node %i: %i\n", rank, cpu_count);
    printf("OpenMP (max) thread count on node %i: %i\n", rank, omp_get_num_threads());
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // generate a part of mandelbrot set according to world size and rank of this server
    mandelbrot(rank, world_size, width, part_height);

    // gather parts of mandelbrot from all nodes
    MPI_Gather(send_buffer, (width)*(part_height)*3, MPI_CHAR, recv_buffer, (width)*(part_height)*3, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    // save raster array of mandelbrot data to png file
    if(rank == 0) save_to_png(width, height);


    printf("Process %i finished.\n", rank);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I am running OpenMPI from Debian repositories, and my OS is Debian 11. (on both machines)

I tried to change `-np` parameter for `-n` with no effect.
If I run two processes on same machine with `mpirun -np 2 --host 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1 ./mandelbrot_mpi_omp` then it works flawlessly, it launches two processes which will do their job fine.
If I stop the task on both computers with CTRL+Z (while inifnitely waiting and not actually running) then it gives me an error:

```
ORTE does not know how to route a message to the specified daemon
located on the indicated node:

  my node:   <hostname placeholder>
  target node:  <real ip here>
```

but those machines can communicate, i can ping them and connect to each other with ssh. They have same username and password.

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to restrict the network interfaces to a known working network. For example `mpirun --mca oob_tcp_if_include eth0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth0 -np 2 ...`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet doesn't work for me. I entered the only interface the machine have - enp6s0 for one and enp5s0 for second.... still infinitely waiting

Comment: you there are multiple interface names, you need to use ip/mask (e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) do you have any firewall on/between the hosts? do you have several IP on the hosts?

Comment: just one with loopback device on each machine and only one ip address. There is not any firewall between the hosts, they are connected to router without any firewall. I will try to specify the mask

Comment: you can  `mpirun --mca oob_base_verbose 100 ...` in order to gather logs.

Comment: ok, so i specified mask and it still cant initialize properly. what's weird is that it tries to connect to some ip address `0.0.0.192` which will expectedly end up with "connection timed out" error. i try to run it with: `mpirun --mca oob_base_verbose 100 --mca oob_tcp_if_include enp5s0 --mca btl_tcp_if_include enp5s0 -np 2 --host 192.168.0.147/24,192.168.0.116/24 ./mandelbrot_mpi_omp`, where `enp5s0` is `enp6s0` on second machine.
my logs are: https://pastebin.com/R59UNNDi
and when it tries to connect i ran lsof command to gaher opened ports: https://pastebin.com/sqwDYz75

Comment: the command should be `mpirun --mca oob_base_verbose 100 --mca oob_tcp_if_include 192.168.0.0/24 --mca btl_tcp_if_include 192.168.0.0/24 -np 2 --host 192.168.0.147,192.168.0.116 ./mandelbrot_mpi_omp`

Comment: nope, still doesn't work, but with one difference, that the ssh port has `CLOSE_WAIT` status on both machines. From what I read it means the connection must have started, but why would it end before the program initialization?
here is my lsof pastebin: https://pastebin.com/s3HHFWZB

Comment: I did not expect this command to work, but I expected you post updated logs so I can have a look. `CLOSE_WAIT` simply means the `orted` daemon (spawned with ssh`) has completed. This is a symptom and not the cause.

Comment: here's the log from both machines: https://pastebin.com/bt32ZddX

Comment: that's odd since there is no error message... on which machine did you invoke this command? what if you `iptables -L` (as root) on both machines? note ping and SSH is not enough for MPI to work between hosts.

Comment: i ran this command on both machines, and `iptables` seems not to be installed, `nftables` is not installed too.

Comment: This is odd since a given machine does not display anything from the daemon spawned (via ssh) on the other machine (!)

Comment: are there other ways to launch this program on multiple machines through openmpi?
also i heard about some smpd daemon automatically launching applications when invoked only by one computer, but it seems that this implementation (openmpi) does not have it... is there an alternative for it in openmpi? if yes how would I invoke that?

Comment: just to make sure, can you ssh **passwordless** between hosts?

Comment: yup, this was the problem, i couldnt...
but now i have set up passwordless ssh login and now it works.
thanks! such a simple thing and i didn't think about it.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I couldn't login via ssh passwordless. Once I set it up to be possible to login to other pcs passwordless by generating pair of rsa keys on both machines, it works.